# Regular expression in Javascript (without jQuery)?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and recently I wanted to use regular expression in order to get a number from url and store it into a var as string and another var as digit. For example I want to get the number 55 from the below webpage (which is not an accrual page) and I want to store it in a var.

I tried this but it is not working

```
https://www.google.com/55.html
    url.replace(/(\d+)(\.html)$/, function(str, p1, p2) {
                    return((Number(p1) + 1) + p2);
```

Please I need help but not with jQuery because it does not make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: If you're trying to get a number, why are you calling `replace`?

Comment: Are you saying the number you want to retrieve will always be between the last `/` and `.html`? And you'll never have something like `www.something.com/test55.html`?

Comment: it is always a number, and only a number

Answer (score 1):

```
var numPortion = url.match(/(\d+)\.html/)[1]
```

(Assumes a match; if it might not match, check the results before applying the array subscript.)

Comment: @JoeTuskan I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Nice, I usually don't get to chuckle on SO!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var a="https://www.google.com/55.html";
var match = a.match(/(\d+)(\.html)/);
```

match is an array,
match[0] contains the matched expression from your script,
match[1] is the number (the 1st parenthesis),
and so on

Comment: I tried this :var a = location.href;
var match = a.match(/(\d+)(\.html)/);
    
<img src="Images/'  +match+ '.jpg"> still it is not working

Comment: Perhaps I didn't give my array a good name. Try this: <img src="Images/' +match[1] + '.jpg">

Comment: does it matter if it is a string or a digit ?

Comment: no, but the 1st group of () is looking for a number, so in match[1] you'll have something that looks like a number. If the url is not of this format (<number>.html), than the regular expression doesn't match and aout array, match, will be null.

Comment: Now I have this <script>var a = location.href;
var match = a.match(/(\d+)(\.html)/);
</script>
<img src="Images/' +match[1] + '.jpg"> but I do not know why it is not working ?

Comment: do you know how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com/55.html';
var yournumber = /(\d+)(\.html)$/.exec(url);
yournumber = yournumber && yournumber[1];  // <-- shortcut for using if else
```